# How to move interface into nonstandard network namespace as unprivileged user

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, namespace, network-namespaces

I have a Linux network namespace bind mounted at `~/mynamespace` as follows:

```
unshare -mrn;
touch ~/mynamespace; # executed in the console opened by the first command
unshare --net=~/mynamespace true; # executed in the console opened by the first command
```

How can I move an interface from the anonymous network namespace created by command #1 into the namespace bind mounted at `~/mynamespace`?

Note that bind mounting the inner namespace or a copy of it into `/var/run/netns` is not an option in my case, not even temporarily. I think that the `ip ... netns` related commands will only accept a network namespace which is bind mounted in the more standard `/var/run/netns/` directory. So I don't think the `ip` command will work in this case.

Also note that all commands above are run without root as an unprivileged user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unshare -mrn # which implies -U
```

Everything else below is run from the namespace(s) entered from above unless told otherwise.

---

### Without using `ip netns`

```
touch $HOME/mynamespace
unshare --net=$HOME/mynamespace true
```

Here `true` ended, losing any PID reference but a mount reference was kept allowing this namespace to still exist.

The [`ip link set ... netns`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-link.8#ip_link_set_-_change_device_attributes) command can take a mountpoint *or* a process id as reference:

> netns *NETNSNAME* | ***PID***
>
> move the device to the network namespace associated with name NETNSNAME **or process *PID***.

```
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
```

Without using `ip netns` we can still create a PID with a temporary `sleep` command to get a PID reference with the `ip link` command and use it:

```
nsenter --net=$HOME/mynamespace sleep 99 & pid=$!

ip link set veth1 netns $pid
```

which gets:

```
# ip -br link
lo               DOWN           00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK> 
veth0@if2        DOWN           86:c2:bc:ba:1a:01 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> 
# nsenter --net=$HOME/mynamespace ip -br link
lo               DOWN           00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK> 
veth1@if3        DOWN           86:e3:a1:ce:48:4e <BROADCAST,MULTICAST>
```

---

### Using `ip netns`

`ip netns` requires using a shared mounted `/run/netns` to work, or will create and mount one if not already mounted (which happens on first use). If it detects one already mounted, it won't create it and this will fail later (`Cannot create namespace file "/run/netns/foo": Permission denied`) because it belongs to real initial user namespace root and thus can't be written into. If it's not created it can't create it because it can't write in `/run` which belongs to real initial user namespace root. Etc. in all various cases, `ip netns` fails when run from an user namespace without privileges.

Just manually mount one over the previous one, so `ip netns` will be happy:

- if `/run/netns` exists and one wants to keep the current `/run` for some reason:

  ```
  mount -t tmpfs --make-rshared tmpfs /run/netns
  ```
- if `/run/netns` doesn't even exist or even if it exists one can override the whole `/run`:

  One can't create a directory in the current `/run` so it also has to be mounted over, losing access to some other useful information, but opening access to other failing tools (like `iptables-legacy -w` which would otherwise tell `Fatal: can't open lock file /run/xtables.lock: Permission denied`).

  ```
  mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /run
  ```

Now every standard `ip netns`, `ip link` or `ip -n foo ...` command will work as usual in the user namespace:

```
ip netns add mynamespace
ip link add name veth0 type veth peer netns mynamespace name veth1
```

which gets:

```
# ip -br link
lo               DOWN           00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK> 
veth0@if2        DOWN           2a:98:7f:83:bf:9e <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> 
# ip -n mynamespace -br link
lo               DOWN           00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK> 
veth1@if2        DOWN           96:3c:5e:a6:a4:4a <BROADCAST,MULTICAST>
```